# Error when trying to store JSON data in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to show some JSON data on my website from external URL. When run the script I get this error from the chrome console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at
>   JSON.parse ()

**Javascript:**

```
var json = $.getJSON("url");

var a = JSON.parse(json.responseText);

var result = a.query.results.rate;

document.write(result[0].Rate);
```

When I type `console.log(result)` in the console it returns *undefined*

**JSON:**

```
{
"query": {
    "count": 6,
    "created": "2016-12-21T19:18:22Z",
    "lang": "en-US",
    "diagnostics": {
        "url": [{
                "execution-start-time": "1",
                "execution-stop-time": "2",
                "execution-time": "1",
                "content": "url"
            }, {
                "execution-start-time": "5",
                // more of this
            ]

            "results": {
                "rate": [{
                        "id": "GBPUSD",
                        "Name": "GBP/USD",
                        "Rate": "1.2371",
                    },

                    {
                        "id": "GBPEUR",
                        // more of this
                    },

                }
            ]
        }
```

I can't make any changes on the JSON file, but I checked it and it is valid.

P.S. When I write the JavaScript code in the chrome console it works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am guessing the u is the first letter of `undefined`

Comment: I just ran the sample JSON through [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org/) - it looks like the outer json object isn't quite closed properly...

Comment: Did you try to put a "?callback=" string at the end of your request URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
var json = $.getJSON("url");
```

This is an asynchronous operation, you need to give it time to load, something like this would work:

```
$.getJSON("url").done(function(response) {
    var result = response.query.results.rate;
    document.write(result[0].Rate);
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much it works!

Answer (score 0):

It will work in the console if you execute each line with a bit of time in between AS response will have had time to complete and populate responseText. You need to rite the main code in a callback or promise chain after $.getJSON has completed.

Perhaps...

```
$.getJSON("url").then(function(data){
    var result = data.query.results.rate;
    document.write(result[0].Rate);
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much it works too!